# How to get a value of an array that contains objects and arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, spotify

Im trying to get specific values from an array that is in another array. To be clear im using the Spotify Web API and want to get the name of the tracks of an playlist.

The array looks like that (Hope you can understand how it looks like^^) :

```
Object
tracks: Object
        items: Array [4]
               0: Object
                 track: Object
                        name
               1: Object
                 track: Object
                        name
               [...]
```

Now i have in my Ionic/Angular app the angular-spotify module and i was trying to get the name with the following code:

```
Spotify
.getPlaylist('User-ID', 'Playlist-ID')
.then(function (data) {
  console.log(data); 
  arrayLength = data.tracks.items.length;
  for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(track[i]);
  }
});
```

But the console saying me that name isnt defined, where did i make the mistake?

Comment: If you want to iterate over items then you can do this
```alert(data.tracks.items[i].track.name)```

Comment: Thank you, easier than i thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not defined `track` variable, so you can define it inside the loop.

```
track = data.tracks.items[i];
```

Comment: If i write that, the alert give me also an "undefined". But i tried that suggestion, that was in the comments under the question and that helped.

Comment: alert(track) should give you expected result, if you'll add initialization of track.